# Resources to check and correct/explain grammar in sentences

Tags: syntax, resources

I still feel really novice in my Japanese, especially in regards to grammar and sentence structure, but I want to start piecing together the vocabulary I've learned into full sentences in the hope that I can at least marginally communicate next time I visit Japan. My main issue is that I have no real way of knowing if the sentences I create are correct or not. I tried running them through Google Translate, but it feels like Google Translate just takes a best guess about what you are trying to say, so even if the sentence I came up with is completely incorrect, it may still "translate" correctly.

I've been using ChatGPT, and it feels like it's doing a good job, but I have no idea if it's actually accurate. Is there a better resource out there that will work well for this type of self-learning?

To give a recent example of a communication with ChatGPT. One thing I noted is it said it removed a redundant が, but it actually added a second が, so I know it's explanation isn't 100% truthful in regards to what it did, but the rest sounds like it makes sense:

> Is 日本語が少しわかりでも学びです。grammatically correct? If it is not, what
> corrections need to be made to make it grammatically correct?

> The phrase "日本語が少しわかりでも学びです" is not grammatically correct. It seems
> like you're trying to express "I understand a little Japanese and am
> learning," but it needs some adjustments. Here's a corrected version:
>
> "日本語が少しわかりますが、まだ学んでいます。"
>
> This translates to "I understand a little Japanese, but I'm still
> learning." This version is grammatically correct and conveys the
> intended meaning.

> Please explain all of the differences you made between my sentence and
> the grammatically correct sentence, and why they were needed

> Certainly, let's break down the differences between your original
> sentence and the corrected one:
>
> Original sentence: "日本語が少しわかりでも学びです。" Corrected sentence:
> "日本語が少しわかりますが、まだ学んでいます。"
>
> "わかりでも" vs. "わかりますが":
>
> In your original sentence, "わかりでも" doesn't convey the intended
> meaning. "でも" means "but" or "however," which doesn't fit here.
> Instead, "わかりますが" (understand but) correctly introduces a contrast
> between understanding a little Japanese and the ongoing process of
> learning.
>
> "学び" vs. "学んでいます":
>
> "学び" (manabi) is the dictionary form of the verb "to learn." However,
> to convey the ongoing action of learning, you need to use the present
> progressive form. Therefore, "学んでいます" (manande imasu) or its
> colloquial form "学んでいます" (manande iru) is more appropriate.
>
> Redundant "が":
>
> Your original sentence had an unnecessary "が" before "でも." This was
> removed in the corrected sentence to maintain grammatical accuracy.
>
> Omission of "です":
>
> While your original sentence ends with "学びです," it's more common and
> natural in Japanese to use the verb ending "ます" or "います" when
> expressing ongoing actions. Therefore, "です" is omitted in the
> corrected sentence.

Comment: It seems like ChatGPT can produce correct sentences but cannot explain the grammar well.. Have you tried HiNative?

Comment: @chocolate Meta行き...?

Comment: @naruto "Questions seeking resources" で off-topic として閉めるべきか、迷ってました・・

Comment: @chocolate [これ](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2389/5010)がアリならこれもMetaでいいのかなと